# Get value of textbox from .html()

Tags: jquery, html

I am using .html() function to create a textbox but unable to get its value.

```
var inner_html_content = '<body><p><br>some_text</p> <input type="text" name="rtn_resn" id="retn_rsn" style="width: 80%;""></body>';

$('<div/>').html(inner_html_content);

var value = $(this).find("#retn_rsn").val();
```

But it is always returning undefined. How to get the value from textbox?

Comment: Can we have a sample of your html so we can try to make your code working ?

Comment: You are creating a new div, and putting the html in it, but never attaching the div to the dom.  So it is being lost.

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to?

Comment: `this` in the scope of the code you've shown will be the `window`, not the `div` you just created. To fix this you need to store a reference to the jQuery object you create which contains the `div`, then call `find()` on that. However it's worth noting that you don't necessarily need to create that outer div if you only want to get the value of the input, and more importantly, the input itself has no `value` attribute to read, so the output will always be nothing.

Comment: It should also be noted that it is not valid HTML to have a body tag be a child of a div.

Comment: try this $("#retn_rsn").val();

Comment: I am trying to create a textbox in js file that is the reason I am passing the html as string.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reading the input field value

You get the value from an input field using `.val()`, not `.html()` -- though since you're creating that field with an empty value, this will  give an empty result:

```js
$('#container').html('<input id="retn_rsn">')
console.log($("#retn_rsn").val()) // empty string
// Now replace it with one that has a value:
$('#container').html('<input id="retn_rsn" value="test">')
console.log($("#retn_rsn").val()) // not empty string
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

So that's the full answer of how to do this, above.  Below are the details on why you got the results you did:

#### `$('<div>')` is not the same as `$('div')`

One reason you're getting `undefined` rather than an empty string stems from this line:

```
$('<div/>').html(inner_html_content);
```

This does *not* insert the HTML into the existing document; it creates a new, separate document fragment and inserts the HTML into that instead.  Later, when you try to query the main document, you'll find no match, because that's not where you added the input:

```js
var foo = $('<div/>').html("TEST"); // capturing the newly created fragment in `foo`
console.log($('#container').html()) // no change in main document
console.log(foo.html()) // but the separate document fragment exists
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

What you probably intended to use was this:

```
$('div').html(inner_html_content);
```

...though note that this would insert the html into *every* div in the page, which almost certainly isn't what you want; you should use a more specific selector for the insertion point.

#### What `this` is depends on its context

Another problem is in your use of `this` here, which doesn't refer to what you think it does:

```
var value = $(this).find("#retn_rsn").val();
```

In the context shown in your question, `this` refers to the `window` object rather than the document body, so `find()` on it will return nothing:

```js
console.log(this === window) // true
console.log($(window).find('#container').length) // 0 
console.log($(document).find('#container').length) // 1 (the document contains the html, not the window)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

In other contexts, `this` can refer to other objects -- but rather than explain this in even more excruciating detail than I've already gone to in this answer, I'll just point out that you've no need to use `this` at all! The element you're looking for has a specific ID, so just use `$('#retn_rsn')` instead of `$(this).find('#retn_rsn')`.

#### Bonus question you didn't ask: nested `<body>` tags

Inserting a `<body>` tag inside the body of an existing document would result in invalid HTML.  Fortunately jQuery appears to fix this for you by silently dropping the invalid nested `<body>` tag:

```js
$('#container').html('<body>...</body>')

console.log($('#container').html()) // `body` tag removed
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

...but it'd be better to not try to include it in the first place.